# How to attach user comments to order as PDF

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pdf-generation

In my WooCommerce website, users can enter comments - such as a gift message. I then integrate with a 3rd party warehouse software called MintSoft. My warehouse have told me the only way they can include gift messages is if I attach the message as a printable PDF/DOCX file to the order. I assume if I attach a file to the order in WooCommerce, that will feed down to MintSoft.

So my question is, how can - upon order execution - I generate a PDF/DOCX file based on a 6x4 inch template, populating it with the user comments field from the WooCommerce order, then attach that generated file to the order in WooCommerce?

I have searched for a plugin that does this, but no luck.

Comment: Broad question, but I guess if you manage to create the file with the comment, you will be able to send it with `woocommerce_email_attachments` filter. Did you manage to create the file?

Comment: Not yet no, I think I will need a third party library to generate it from PHP by hooking into the post-order hook, but still trying to figure out where that is!